# Obtain user and host who inserted data MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am facing a problem with some data in my current database. There is a collection which is being populated and update through a NodeJS application.
This collection possess a children which is an array of objects. I've observed this array gets some objects which I am not sure how they got there. I have traced the application and made sure this is not the culprit.

Therefore I would like to know if there is any way to know what user and host updated a collection and the data it used. Or to get the log of run queries against a collection.

I have used `getLog` but it's limited to 1024 characters so not that much to check there.

**Edit 1**
This is the config file:

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am only the developer of this system and I don't have any control over these things. But our concern is not about non-authorized accessess. The data being created happens always 2-3 seconds before the one being inserted by the application and it happens for specific type of records in that collection. Therefore this is not a non-authorized person inserting stuff. There must be some other system, part of the application or whatever inserting at the same time and I want to find what.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you can check, who logged in to your MongoDB. Make a `grep "Successful authentication"` on your mongo logfile.

Then you can increase the logging level for commands, put this in your config file:

```
systemLog:
  component:
    command:
      verbosity: 1
```

Be aware, the log file may become big.

With the [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) tool it would be similar to this:

```
jq -r 'select(.msg == "Successful authentication")' /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

jq -r 'select(.c == "COMMAND")' /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
```